FormatException with ILogger after project upgradation from .NET 6.0 to 8.0
I am upgrading a existing running project from .NET 6.0 to 8.0 and ILogger and Serilog are in use and it is running perfectly(no logging error/warning) with .NET 6.0.
Here is the sample code
//HomeController.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

public void Foo()
{
     string roles = "A,B,C,D,E";
     string methodName = "Foo()"
     _logger.LogDebug(roles, typeof(HomeController), methodName);
}

Actually, the above _logger.LogDebu(...) first message parameter has not placeholder to accept it's second and third params argument but the same code is not throwing exception but in .NET 8 it is throwing error. (In .NET 6.0, the passed params argumets just ignored by logger but no error)

If I will modify it as following code, then it will work fine but I
don't have to do it if any alternate option is available to get rid from 200+ lines changes

public void Foo()
{
         string roles = "A,B,C,D,E | {arg1} | {arg2}"; //message formatted to accept arguments
         string methodName = "Foo()"
         _logger.LogDebug(roles, typeof(HomeController), methodName);
}

Excepted Answer

Kindly suggest, how to fix it without doing message format correction
in entire application. I had thought to write extension method to
correct message format there but it still needs changes in whole
application.

Changes
I did following changes in application during .NET upgradation

Project upgraded to .NET 8.0
All dependent NuGet packages updated with latest available version
Serilog.AspNetCore upgraded from version 4.1.0 to 8.0.1 , also updated other Serilog packages like Serilog.Sinks.file,

Error Screenshot


Go through this link
